# Infinite-dimensional representation theory

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ be its Lie algebra. Denote the universal enveloping algebra by $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$.

When studying finite-dimensional unitary representations $(\pi,V)$ of $G$, we have that if $G$ is connected then $(\pi,V)$ is irreducible if and only if the Lie algebra representation $(\pi_*,V)$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ is irreducible. This is also equivalent to the extension $(\tilde{\pi}_*,V)$ being irreducible as an associative algebra representation of $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$.

I am looking for a reference which explains how this can be extended to the infinite dimensional case. How does one 'differentiate' the representation (can we even do this in a sensible way?) and is there an analog to the above equivalences of irreducibility?

Comment: One way would be to take only those vectors on which you can derive the action. This subspace happens to be dense, and carries almost all information of the original representation. Look for Harish-Chandra modules (e.g. Chapter 2 in D. Vogan: Unitary Representations of Reductive Lie Groups).

Comment: Thanks for replying. My main source of confusion comes from p.112 of Varadarajan's 'Introduction to Harmonic Analysis on Semisimple Lie Groups' (you can find it on google books): he treats the representation theory of the Lie algebra on a purely algebraic level. For example, 'irreducible' means no nontrivial invariant subspaces at all, whereas for the group one typically demands nonexistence of nontrivial invariant *closed* subspaces. Why this difference? It would seem to mess up the equivalence I stated in my post.